# Compile error when using a member of a user-defined literal

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

When compiling this code (without any header)

```
template <typename T>
struct Temperature {
    T temp;

    explicit Temperature(T t)
        : temp(t)
    {}
};

Temperature<long double> operator "" _f (long double t)
{
    return Temperature<long double>((t - 32) / 1.8);
}

int main()
{
    auto t = 100.0_f;
    t.temp;

    100.0_f.temp; // ERROR AT THIS LINE
    return 0;
}
```

The compilers (both g++ 4.8 and clang++ 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04) will complain that

```
error: unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator"" _f.temp’
     100.0_f.temp;
     ^
```

It seems that the `_f.temp` is considered as a suffix there. Why do the compilers parse it like that, instead of stopping at the dot?

Comment: Maximal munch. `100.0_f.temp` is a valid *pp-number* token.

Comment: Change to `(100.0_f).temp`

Comment: @T.C. Have no idea that a pp-number token could contain more than one dot. Could you show me an example in such a form?

Comment: @T.C. [lex.pptoken]/1 seems to suggest that `100.0_f.temp` doesn't pass the preprocessing phase?

Comment: @M.M It fails conversion to token, of course, so the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Preprocessing numbers](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ppnumber) are odd beasts, specified mostly to make the preprocessor easier to write.

```
pp-number:
    digit
    . digit
    pp-number digit
    pp-number identifier-nondigit
    pp-number ' digit
    pp-number ' nondigit
    pp-number e sign
    pp-number E sign
    pp-number p sign
    pp-number P sign
    pp-number .
```

`12` is a valid *pp-number* token, so is `0xe+foo` (see the example in [lex.pptoken]/4), and so is `.12.CA'TS_RULE..56.me+owp-urr`. If the latter two make it past translation phase 6, then the program is ill-formed because it cannot be converted to a valid token in phase 7. Until then, however, it is valid, so maximal munch says we parse `0xe+foo` or `100.0_f.temp` as a single preprocessing token.

Comment: Really beasts. Hope the standard gives an update to make codes easier to write.

Comment: I would never have thought `0xe+foo` could be invalid C++, this seems so wrong...