# Error subtracting hex constant when it ends in an 'E'

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
int main()
{
    0xD-0; // Fine
    0xE-0; // Fails
}
```

This second line fails to compile on both clang and gcc. Any other hex constant ending is ok (0-9, A-D, F).

Error:

```
<source>:4:5: error: unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""-0'
    4 |     0xE-0;
      |     ^~~~~
```

I have a fix (adding a space after the constant and before the subtraction), so I'd mainly like to know why? Is this something to do with it thinking there's an exponent here?

https://godbolt.org/z/MhGT33PYP

Comment: Edit: I've found https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=3885 which may explain this

Comment: A parsing error worth reporting, but I doubt you really need to subtract two literals, it would typically go like `constexpr int BASE = 0xE; BASE-0;` anyway

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with how C++ interprets `E+...` or `E-...`. It must be first interpreting `-0` as part of the number due to the `E` before it, then realising that its an invalid suffix in this case (as it's not an integer suffix at all). Just a guess, though. I'd love to find out why this happens.

Comment: Yeah - I guess it's confused about whether or not to treat the `E-0` as a floating-point exponent. As mentioned in the linked bug report, adding spaces around the `-` sign resolves the issue, it seems.

Comment: After digging around in the docs, I've found out why. I'll add an answer now.

Comment: Note that clang-cl (in VS 2022) has no issue with this.

Comment: @AdrianMole a bug on Clang-cl behalf if its accepting it. As in the reported bug it appears to be "no bug".

Comment: Existing answer to same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49543516/why-doesnt-0xe1-compile

Comment: Also see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal which says: `Due to maximal munch, hexadecimal integer literals ending in e and E, when followed by the operators + or -, must be separated from the operator with whitespace or parentheses in the source:`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, this behaviour is mandated by the C++ standard (and documented), as strange as it may seem. This is because of how C++ compiles using [*Preprocessing Tokens (a.k.a pp-tokens)*](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/tools/clang_cpp_tokens.html#:%7E:text=operators%2C%20and%20punctuators.-,Preprocessing%20numbers,e%2B%20e%2D%20E%2B%20E%2D.&text=the%20preprocessing%20number%202e%20is%20not%20a%20valid%20number.).

If we look closely at how the compiler generates a token for numbers:

> A preprocessing number is made up of a digit, optionally preceded by a period, and may be followed by letters, underscores, digits, periods, and any one of: e+ e- E+ E-.

According to this, The compiler reads `0x`, then `E-`, which it interprets it as part of the number as having `E-` is allowed in a numeral pp-token and no space precedes it or is in between the `E` and the `-` (this is why adding a space is an easy fix).

This means that `0xE-0` is taken in as a **single** preprocessing token. In other words, the compiler interprets it as one number, instead of two numbers `0xE` and `0` and an operation `-`. Therefore, the compiler is expecting `E` to represent an exponent for a floating-point literal.

Now let's take a look at how C++ interprets [floating-point literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal). Look at the section under "Examples". It gives this curious code sample:

```
    << "\n0x1p5         " << 0x1p5        // double
    << "\n0x1e5         " << 0x1e5        // integer literal, not floating-point
```

`E` is interpreted as part of the integer literal, and does **not** make the number a *hexadecimal floating literal*! Therefore, the compiler recognizes `0xE` as a single, integer, hexidecimal number. Then, there is the `-0` which is technically part of the same preprocessing token and therefore is not an operator and another integer. Uh oh. This is now invalid, as there is no `-0` suffix.

And so the compiler reports an error, as such.

Comment: Should add credit to [comment](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=3885#c2) section on the reported bug.